# What is a typical Cd0 value for single-slotted flaps?

Tags: aircraft-design, drag

I've been having trouble finding any source for what a typical value would be for single-slotted flaps. I haven't been able to find any information within Anderson's Aircraft Performance and Design or any other resource readily available.

Thank you so much!